# bbappend ignored by image

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I have created a bbappend file with the recipetool included in the toolchain. My resulting file `project-spec/meta-user/recipes-containers/docker/docker-ce_git.bbappend` is quite simple, I just want to add a file in the rootfs

```
ino_move_docker_data() {
    echo "{" >> ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/etc/docker/daemon.json
    echo '  "data-root": "/data/docker"' >> ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/etc/docker/daemon.json
    echo "}" >> ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/etc/docker/daemon.json
}

ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND += " ino_move_docker_data;"
```

And when I run `bitbake -e docker-ce`, I can see `ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND=" set_user_group; set_sudoers; ino_move_docker_data;"`. So the function is correctly added.

However, when I try to build my full image, its not there, and `bitbake -e my_image` does not contain my function in `ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND`

My image is in `project-spec/meta-user/recipes-core/images/` and doker is added with `IMAGE_INSTALL`

I'm pretty new to yocto/bitbake/petalinux, so I'm sorry if it's an obvious question

Comment: The `ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND` is used by the rootfs-postcommands class - however it wasn't meant to be inherited by regular (package) recipes, but by image recipes. Try to add your command rather to the image recipe itself.

Comment: @skandigraun ok that explains why it doesnt work. What you propose will work, but I would prefer to do the change in a bbappend to keep the change specific to this recipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @skandigraun [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77204821/bbappend-ignored-by-image?noredirect=1#comment136108904_77204821), the `ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND` is not processed because it's regular recipe

What I ended up doing:

file: project-spec/meta-user/recipes-containers/docker/docker-ce_git.bbappend

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS:append := "${THISDIR}/files:"
SRC_URI += "file://daemon.json"

do_install:append() {
    install -d ${D}${base_prefix}/etc/docker/
    install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/daemon.json ${D}${base_prefix}/etc/docker/
}

FILES_${PN}:append = " ${base_prefix}/etc/docker/daemon.json "
```

file: project-spec/meta-user/recipes-containers/docker/files/daemon.json

```
{
  "data-root": "/data/docker"
}
```